# Can I bring a friction lock baton to Dubai?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, dubai, cold-weapons

Is it legal to import and possess a friction-lock baton in Dubai for self-defence purposes?

Comment: How is this travel related ?

Comment: Are you asking if its okay to carry it with you _to_ Dubai?

Comment: I presume you're not asking about a conductor's baton.

Comment: @phoog I presume, he's talking about a friction lock baton, like Asp or Monadnock.  They can be bought in UK for about £40-50, as far as I know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel but legality of an object in other countries.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid yes, exaclty. And yes, I mean friction lock baton

Comment: @blackbird57 I edited question to clarify

Comment: I think it's just a bad idea but the question is clearly related to travel so I voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is not as simple to answer as it may seem. A friction lock baton is not classified as a weapon (meaning it doesn't require a special license), as per Federal Law # 3 of 2009, which defines weapons as:

> a ‘weapon’ as: Including a firearm, air gun, sound gun, flare gun,
>   hunting gun, antique gun and stun guns; and
>
> a ‘firearm’ as: A weapon that launches a projectile by the pressure
>   resulting from the combustion of the propellant material. This
>   definition excludes the air gun, sound gun and photo gun. However, it
>   states any firearm parts, components or spare parts shall be
>   considered firearms.

In practice, replica weapons also need special permits to be imported.

This means that you don't need a permit to import it into the UAE. However, a baton is considered a weapon as far as the airline and transport industry is concerned, and is listed in the list of things prohibited in carry-on luggage by the UAE airport regulator:

> 1. All types of hammers
> 2. All types of nails
> 3. All types of screwdrivers and sharp work tools
> 4. All types of scissors with blades longer than 6cm
> 5. Personal grooming kit (parts longer than 6cm will be confiscated)
> 6. All types of swords and sharp objects
> 7. Handcuffs
> 8. All types of laser guns
> 9. All types of replica firearms
> 10. All types of firearms, ammunition and flare guns
> 11. All types of lighters (only one lighter is permitted)
> 12. **All types of bats**
> 13. **All types of martial art weapons**
> 14. Drills
> 15. All types of ropes
> 16. All types of measuring tapes
> 17. Packing tape
> 18. Electrical cables except for personal use
> 19. Walkie-talkie

You can find a similar list for example, at [etihad airways website](http://www.etihad.com/en-us/before-you-fly/baggage-information/prohibited-items/).

So, in short:

1. You can import it in, without a license.
2. You can check it in your luggage, but not carry it with you on-board.

If you walk around brandishing it, you will most likely get stopped by police as it is illegal to carry weapons in public.

Comment: "illegal to carry weapons in public" - do you mean open carry or carrying it at all? Is concealed carrying permitted?

Comment: No it is not permitted. There are no conceal and carry permits in the UAE - and for that matter, throughout most of the Middle East. Weapons are common and are used in hunting and some cultural events, however these require special permits (not granted to non-citizen individuals, but are granted to non-citizen companies, for example - a weapons exhibitor), and those are very restrictive and the penalties can be harsh.  Due to some recent events, some ME countries have cracked down even harder on weapons use; requiring citizens to register them and stiffer penalties for violators.

Comment: Where are the references to the text you quote? Don't plagiarise. ;)

Comment: The text of the law is from the ... err ... law; and the second text let me find the reference online, but I remember the list from a circular that was published.