# Can I import a replica gun in the UAE?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, uae, firearms

I was wondering if it's allowed to import replica guns in the UAE. I was thinking of importing a realistic replica m1911 for collecting purposes. Will it be stopped at the customs? Is it a criminal offense?

Answer (score 6):

As described in [UAE Federal Law No. 3 of 2009 on Weapons, Ammunitions, and Explosives](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0QgFptQVvTMQk4tUUd4S2tUdzQ), there are regulations regarding the possession of firearms, including those that may be replica or antique. It also limits possession to those who are older than 25 years of age, per Article 11.4, "It shall be prohibited to grant licenses to the persons under 25 years of age."

Therefore, firearms are included in the [United Arab Emirates list of Prohibited And Restricted](http://www.dubaicustoms.gov.ae/en/Publications/Publications/DC_Tariff_PRG_ENG.pdf) items:

> [Dubai Customs] Prohibition and Restriction Section aims to regulate rules and principles of prohibiting or restricting goods ensuring accurate execution in alignment
>   with the GCC Customs Unified Law as well as other related laws and systems.
>
> **Example of Restricted Goods In UAE**
>   **Product Title/Description**: All kind of weapons and ammunitions
>  
>   **Restricting Authority**: Ministry of Interior

Weapons require the issuance of a license by the [Weapons Licensing Branch in the Weapons & Explosives Department](https://www.abudhabi.ae/portal/public/en/homepage/safety-and-environment/safety/firearm-licence-issuance)
. This would be done prior to attempting to enter the country with the weapon, and declaring it to the carrier should you be returning by air. Once allowed in, the Weapons Licensing Branch may require inspection of the replica.

UAE nationals can submit a request for the issuance or addition of a firearm licence, which is managed within the Government of [Abu Dhabi Police](https://www.adpolice.gov.ae/ar/Pages/home.aspx) Weapons & Explosives Department. You'll need your passport (original and a copy), a photo, good conduct certificate, health certificate, and copies of your labour card, Emirates ID card, and your full family book. You can address any questions by email to wed@adpolice.gov.ae

Answer (score 3):

If you want to bring into UAE a weapon replica, you would need a specific license.

If you don't have it, here is what can happen :
http://www.tamimi.com/en/magazine/law-update/section-11/section-13/the-legal-possession-of-weapons-in-the-uae.html

Another post that talks about something similar :
[Can I bring a friction lock baton to Dubai?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71480/can-i-bring-a-friction-lock-baton-to-dubai/71586)

And a website with a lot of details around regulation :
http://www.gunpolicy.org/firearms/region/united-arab-emirates

Comment: Could you please add some authoritative references, quoting them in your post?